Homomorphic signature for linear combination
Say I have an element $g$ of a cyclic group. Are there homomorphic signature schemes that allow deriving signatures of $g^{ax+by}$ from signatures of $g^a$ and $g^b$?

Such a signature scheme cannot exist for the traditional notion of unforgeability, since it would be trivial to forge new signatures. By definition, you shouldn't be able to produce a valid signature of $g^{ax+by}$ from signatures of $g^a$ and $g^b$ without the secret key.

@lamontap Thank you for your comment.

I seem to have misled you with my previous comment. I just realized that homomorphic signatures actually are a thing. They just adapt the unforgeability game to being unable to forge a signature for a message that is not a linear combination of previously signed messages.
